# R- Remove several rows based on a value

Tags: r, database, filter

I have checked several anwers for this type of issues but I'm still not sure of how to make it. I have a data set like this:

```
Year Month stn1 stn2
1980   1    8     4
1980   2    4     7
1980   3    6     9
1980   4    3     1
1980   5    0     2
1980   6    1     6
1980   7    3     9
1980   8    6     8
1980   9    1     NA
1980   10    2     1
1980   11    1     3
1980   12    4     2
1981   1    8     4
1981   2    4     7
1981   3    6     9
1981   4    NA     1
1981   5    0     2
1981   6    1     6
1981   7    3     9
1981   8    6     8
1981   9    1     5
1981   10    2     1
1981   11    1     3
1981   12    4     2
```

What I want to do is filtrate the rows based on the NA's on the columns "Stn1" and "Stn2". So if there is an NA, it will remove the whole year. 
I want the output to be two data sets that contain only complete years like this:

```
Data1:
Year Month stn1 
1980   1    8     
1980   2    4     
1980   3    6     
1980   4    3     
1980   5    0     
1980   6    1     
1980   7    3     
1980   8    6     
1980   9    1     
1980   10    2     
1980   11    1     
1980   12    4     


Data2:
Year Month stn2
1981   1    4
1981   2    7
1981   3    9
1981   4    1
1981   5    2
1981   6    6
1981   7    9
1981   8    8
1981   9    5
1981   10   1
1981   11   3
1981   12   2
```

The original dataset has more year but I wanted to make it short so it could be more understandable.

**data**

```
df <- read.table(h=T, text="
Year Month stn1 stn2
1980   1    8     4
1980   2    4     7
1980   3    6     9
1980   4    3     1
1980   5    0     2
1980   6    1     6
1980   7    3     9
1980   8    6     8
1980   9    1     NA
1980   10    2     1
1980   11    1     3
1980   12    4     2
1981   1    8     4
1981   2    4     7
1981   3    6     9
1981   4    NA     1
1981   5    0     2
1981   6    1     6
1981   7    3     9
1981   8    6     8
1981   9    1     5
1981   10    2     1
1981   11    1     3
1981   12    4     2")
```

Comment: it would be nice to have your feedback in the comments under icecream toucan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
by(df,df$Year,function(x)x[!colSums(is.na(x))])
df$Year: 1980
   Year Month stn1
1  1980     1    8
2  1980     2    4
3  1980     3    6
4  1980     4    3
5  1980     5    0
6  1980     6    1
7  1980     7    3
8  1980     8    6
9  1980     9    1
10 1980    10    2
11 1980    11    1
12 1980    12    4
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$Year: 1981
   Year Month stn2
13 1981     1    4
14 1981     2    7
15 1981     3    9
16 1981     4    1
17 1981     5    2
18 1981     6    6
19 1981     7    9
20 1981     8    8
21 1981     9    5
22 1981    10    1
23 1981    11    3
24 1981    12    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using the *tidyverse*.

We loop on column names and for each column we

- choose the relevant columns
- filter the 3rd column to keep only groups (years) that don't contain any NA

```r
library(tidyverse)
map(c("stn1","stn2"), ~
      select_at(df, c("Year", "Month",.)) %>%
      group_by(Year) %>%
      filter_at(3,~!anyNA(.)) %>%
      ungroup)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>     Year Month  stn1
#>    <int> <int> <int>
#>  1  1980     1     8
#>  2  1980     2     4
#>  3  1980     3     6
#>  4  1980     4     3
#>  5  1980     5     0
#>  6  1980     6     1
#>  7  1980     7     3
#>  8  1980     8     6
#>  9  1980     9     1
#> 10  1980    10     2
#> 11  1980    11     1
#> 12  1980    12     4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>     Year Month  stn2
#>    <int> <int> <int>
#>  1  1981     1     4
#>  2  1981     2     7
#>  3  1981     3     9
#>  4  1981     4     1
#>  5  1981     5     2
#>  6  1981     6     6
#>  7  1981     7     9
#>  8  1981     8     8
#>  9  1981     9     5
#> 10  1981    10     1
#> 11  1981    11     3
#> 12  1981    12     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

For each unique value of `Year`, subset `df` to rows with that year and columns with no NAs.

```
lapply(split(df, df$Year), function(yr)
    yr[sapply(yr, function(col) !any(is.na(col)))]
)

# [[1]]
#    Year Month stn1
# 1  1980     1    8
# 2  1980     2    4
# 3  1980     3    6
# 4  1980     4    3
# 5  1980     5    0
# 6  1980     6    1
# 7  1980     7    3
# 8  1980     8    6
# 9  1980     9    1
# 10 1980    10    2
# 11 1980    11    1
# 12 1980    12    4
# 
# [[2]]
#    Year Month stn2
# 13 1981     1    4
# 14 1981     2    7
# 15 1981     3    9
# 16 1981     4    1
# 17 1981     5    2
# 18 1981     6    6
# 19 1981     7    9
# 20 1981     8    8
# 21 1981     9    5
# 22 1981    10    1
# 23 1981    11    3
# 24 1981    12    2
```

Comment: I think OP wants to loop on stn cols , not on years, though the result is the same in that case

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question, when would the results be different? I was thinking conceptually this is like a nested for-loop where it doesn't matter which loop is inside vs. outside.

Comment: The way I understand it, you could very well have several years in one table, but you should never get several stn columns in one table

Comment: This comment applies to @Onyambu's solution as well

Comment: Oh I see. I guess a clarifying example for OP would be if there was an `stn3` with all non-missing values added, what should the output be in that case.

Comment: (perhaps with another year added if that's more realistic)

Comment: Thnak you so much for all of your answers, I've tried the three methods all of you proposed and I've found that Onyambu and IceCreamToucan methods give the same result, so the both worked well, the only difference is that with 
As far as Moody_Mudskipper's answer it arrange the output on a different way.